# OO Design Pattern on a Package/Assembly/Namespace level?

Tags: design-patterns, assemblies, namespaces, package

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939167/c-circular-reference-and-cannot-see-namespace) and I wondered to myself are there any design patterns/rules of thumb that you can use when breaking up your project into packages/assemblies.

I usually don't seem to have any issues with this as I tend to just break stuff up into packages/assemblies such that each does as little as possible that is relevant to the assembly, but I do sometimes find that I'm at a loss as to whether a class should be in one namespace or another.

Most of the design patterns I've seen help you decide how to structure your classes, but I dont think I've seen any that hel you structure your namespaces?

has anyone else seen any?

Answer (score 0):

Design patters are best practices concerning the behavior and state of code that you write not so much about the organization of that code.  Just think about your types and what they are and what they do, common types will fall into common namespaces.